# Why is onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt being called continuously?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location, android-permissions

I have an app that uses a WebView where sites may request to use the device's geolocation. I have the following in my main activity:

```
public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin, final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
    m_geolocationCallback = null;
    m_geolocationOrigin = null;

    // If we don't have location permissions, we must request them first
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Show rationale if necessary
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.permission_location_rationale, origin))
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            m_geolocationOrigin = origin;
                            m_geolocationCallback = callback;
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
        else {
            m_geolocationOrigin = origin;
            m_geolocationCallback = callback;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }
    // Otherwise just tell webview that permission has been granted
    else {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}
```

To handle the permission request result, `MainActivity` also has the following:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:
            // Permission granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (m_geolocationCallback != null) {
                    m_geolocationCallback.invoke(m_geolocationOrigin, true, false);
                }
            }
            // Permission denied
            else {
                // In this case, the user checked "Don't ask again" and denied permission
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[0])) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_location_denied, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                if (m_geolocationCallback != null) {
                    m_geolocationCallback.invoke(m_geolocationOrigin, false, false);
                }
            }
            return;
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that whenever a site requests to use geolocation and I deny it (resulting in `invoke(origin, false false)` being called), the `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` method is called immediately and I am stuck in a loop of endlessly denying permission to the app.

If I check "don't ask again" in the permission request, it works fine, but  I want to be able to ask the user for permission again at a later point in time.

I've tried fixing this by changing my rejection callback invocation to
`m_geolocationCallback.invoke(m_geolocationOrigin, false, true)`, but this does not produce the desired effect. This will prevent stop the continuous calls to `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt`, but it also means that the given origin can no longer use geolocation even if permissions are later enabled, and I found no way to undo this (even by uninstalling/reinstalling the app).

Any ideas on how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in Android Webview. The endless loop happens if `callback.invoke` is called asynchronously with granted=false, but does not occur if it is called synchronously inside `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt`.

My workaround is to save the time when the user denies the geolocation permission. If `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` is called again within a small amount of time and `checkSelfPermission` does not return PERMISSION_GRANTED, run `callback.invoke(origin, false, false)` and do not re-prompt the user.

Answer (score 0):

we can fix it like below:

```
// set param 'retain' true, to prevent permission request continuously
callback?.invoke(origin, isGranted, true)
if (!isGranted) {
    // clear permission state, so the user can request permission again
    Handler().postDelayed({ GeolocationPermissions.getInstance().clear(origin) }, 500)
}
```